# Android - How to get sensor details based on sensor name?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sensors

I'm writing a simple application as an exercise - display a list of all sensors on the device as a ListView, and display current sensor values/details in a new activity when clicking on each sensor name in the ListView.

I have the ListView working correctly, and can pass the sensor name to the new activity so far. Is there a way to get the sensor details using this passed name? It seems like I cannot use putExtra() to pass the sensor itself to the new activity. Or is there another approach to this?

**SensorList activity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_sensor_activity);

    sensorListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sensorlist);
    sensorListView.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this); //allows each item in ListView to be clickable

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    sensorList = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL); //get list of sensors
    ArrayList<String> sensorNames =  new ArrayList<String>(); //list of sensor names

    //iterate through list of sensors, get name of each and append to list of names
    for(int i=0; i< sensorList.size(); i++) {
        String sensor= sensorList.get(i).getName();
        if(sensor == null || sensor.equals(""))
            continue;
        sensorNames.add(sensor);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sensorNames);
    sensorListView.setAdapter(adapter); //populate ListView with sensor names
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id ) {
    Intent sensorDetails = new Intent(ListSensorActivity.this, SensorDetailActivity.class);
    sensorDetails.putExtra("SENSOR_NAME", sensorList.get(position).getName()); //pass sensor name to detail activity
    startActivity(sensorDetails);
}
```

** SensorDetail activity **

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sensor_detail);

        sensorTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensortitle);

        manager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        sensorName = extras.getString("SENSOR_NAME");
        sensorTitle.setText(sensorName);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the type from the sensor to the second activity, then request the sensor in the activity via SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(type)

Comment: How did you save the variable "type" when you say SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(type)? Im stuck with the same issue here as this.

Comment: @JensO.AndersOlsén There's a series of constants in SensorManager.  Use those.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
 private  SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private  Sensor sensorNames;
```

and in Class

```
 mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
 sensorNames= mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
```

and for passing the value from list as per position:

```
  Intent intent= new Intent(this, SensorDetailActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("SENSOR_NAME", sensorNames.get(position).toString()); 
  startActivity(intent);
```

Let me know if still you are not getting solution.. :)